# Laravel 5.5.39 fresh application Carbon error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, php-carbon

I try to make a new laravel project.
I use Composer version 1.6.3 .
Laravel version is 5.5.39 .
I install the project using the command:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel forum
```

Cd into the project, and use start the server with

```
php artisan serve
```

But, when i open the application i get the following error:

```
DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (2018-03-09 18:14:39.-45868) at position 24 (6): Unexpected character
```

Note that i made no modifications to the folder whatsoever.
This is a new error, since until now i successfully created two little projects.
I dont know what could have changed.

*I installed composer again, made a new project, started the server and it worked. Then i made another project and the error now occurs on both of them.*

Any ideas whats wrong here?

Comment: have you tried `php artisan key:generate`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49199964/laravel-5-5-39-fresh-application-carbon-error

Comment: You were right, thanks :D.
Whats the explanation behind though ?

Comment: I'm not certain of the technical explanation, but the *practical* explanation is that this is clearly listed as one of the installation steps at https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/installation. Make sure you didn't skip the others!

Answer (score 0):

About 4 hours ago  I added a new library to my current laravel project. I used the command: `composer update` and got same error.

Maybe the problem is some update on the Carbon. I deleted the folder

> vendor/nebot/carbon

and replaced it from another carbon folder of another laravel project.

It worked for me.